# Grails - sortableColumn - Forcing numerical sorting on numerical strings

Tags: string, grails, jquery-ui-sortable, numerical

I have number stored in my database as Strings, and I would like to sort them numerically using `Grails sortableColumns`. Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in your database as strings??

Comment: The idea was to create a table for display purposes only. I have a table that in then dedicated for display, and those numbers need to be stored as Strings, as the norm in Brazil is a coma to separate digits, instead of a point

Comment: The formatted view of a number is a display function, and should not be kept in the database.  A database is meant to store the data - therefore it should represent the data it is storing.  It's trivial to apply correct formatting at the time the number is shown.  If you need to sort on it, then you are going to have much poorer performance sorting strings as numbers (no matter how you do it).  Not to mention everything else (comparison, etc.) is slower too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing numbers as formatted strings prevents them from taking advantage of native numerical sorting. Have a look at the Grails formatNumber tag that can use your desired locale to display decimal separators so you can use the actual numeric data and not have to store the formatted string for display purposes.

If the domain class you want to sort has both the formatted and unformatted numeric data, you could try something like this, substituting the sort column param as necessary:

```
def list = {

  if (params?.sort == 'formattedNumber') {
    params.sort = 'rawNumber'
  }

  [ records : Record.list(params) ]
}
```

If your domain class only has the formatted string you can try parsing it to BigDecimal (or whatever the matching numeric type is) but this may not work properly if your server's locale does not match the string format's decimal separator locale.

```
def list = {

  def records = (params?.sort == 'formattedNumber') Record.list().sort{ it.formattedNumber.toBigDecimal() : Record.list(params)
  }

  [ records : records ]
}
```